Fixed Backgroun IOS issue
I have a website that is working great on everything except IOS operating systems.
I have a fixed background that is working great until I look on Iphone.  Here is the Code I used
#content {
background-image: url("https://bluemountain-pools.com/wp-content/uploads/2024/06/hot-tub-smaller.jpg"); no-repeat center;
background-size:cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position:center
}

The Website is www.BlueMountain-Pools.com
The background is only showing a small highly distorted image of the background.
I am using Wordpress for the build
Does anyone have any idea how to code something specific for Iphone for the background image.  I wish I could tell you why it is doing this, but I have no idea.
I don't know what to try.  It works great on Android and on the desktop

add this code to your class .page-id-23 #content
background-size: 100% 100%;

